# How to Add Class to Child Element of Parent using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm attempting to add a class to a **p** tag using the parent tag. Unfortunately, it does not appear to be adding the class **.answer** to the **p** tag. This is the code I have so far:

### HTML

```
<div class="x-acc-content">
  <p>This is sample text.</p>    
</div>
```

### Javascript

```
function($) {
$(this).children('div.x-acc-content').getElementsByTagName('p') [0].addClass('answer');
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.children('p')` to get all children inside your div and then use `.addClass()` to add class to `p` tags .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(".x-acc-content").children("p").addClass("answer")
//or
//$(".x-acc-content").find("p").addClass("answer")
//or only first p tag
//$(".x-acc-content").find("p:first").addClass("answer")
```

```css
.answer {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="x-acc-content">
  <p>This is sample text.</p>
  <p>This is sample text.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(".x-acc-content").find("p").addClass("answer");

or

$(".x-acc-content"). children("p").addClass("answer");

or

$(".x-acc-content p").addClass("answer");
```